# how to prompt confirm dialog on other logged in user screen from administration panel

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

I am developing an internal application with multiple users and one administrator.
i am allowing only 50 users can login into the application at a time, after that i won't allow any other user to logged in.

Now, from admin side i want to kill the specific user session and authentication from logged in users, before killing the user session and authentication i want to prompt a confirm dialog with ok and cancel , depends on the response i want to kill the user.

My question is how to prompt the confirm dialog in the other logged in user screen and how to capture the response.

i am using spring security and angualarjs.

can anyone provide a solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use `confirm()` method of javascript which shows confirm box with an OK and a Cancel button and returns true for Ok and false for Cancel.

Comment: yes. we can do that in the current user screen but i want the same to be display in the other logged in user when click on the kill session of the specific user from the administrator panel.